# How to paint gridview card components background with firestore

Tags: flutter, gridview, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I want to paint each component background by using gridview.count and firestore
Do you have any idea?
And I use model.module

```
return GridView.count(
                primary: false,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                children: workoutList
                                .map(
                            (workout) => CheckboxListTile(
                                title: Text(workout.title),
                                value: workout.isDone,
                                onChanged: (bool value) {
                                workout.isDone = !workout.isDone;
                                model.reload();
                                },
                            ),

                            )
                                .toList(),
                );
```

Comment: Don't put tags in your titles.

Answer (score 0):

I added container  before CheckBoxListTile
That is all

```
children: workoutList
                                .map(
                            (workout) => Container(
                              color: Colors.teal,
                              child: CheckboxListTile(
                                  title: Text(workout.title),
                                  value: workout.isDone,
                                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                                  workout.isDone = !workout.isDone;
                                  model.reload();
                                  },
                              ),
                            ),
```

Comment: if you added material instead of container.
you can use onChanged